# Need to find a way to time-stamp edits done with the changes package

Tags: changes, trackchanges

I have a document which uses the `changes` package. A friend and I are planning to co-author an Analysis textbook, and I have things set-up so that each of us can edit the `.tex` file and then make edits using the `changes` package. Is there a way to date-stamp those edits? Or, is there another package similar to `changes` that would allow for a time-stamp? Also, do I need to add a MWE, or is this a case where the question can be answered without one?

Comment: Therefor you need a version control system like `git` or `svn`. Then you can add information like time-stamp. LaTeX can't save hours/minutes. You can manually add some static specification by `remark={changed 2013/06/13}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Please make your comment here into an answer

Comment: @MarcoDaniel care to answer?

Answer (score 1):

While SVN allows for text substitution, this is somehow not the best way to proceed to obtain the desired results (in LaTeX).

Instead, [`gitinfo2`](https://ctan.org/pkg/gitinfo2) makes available the `\gitCommitterDate` command, which prints the date of the last commit (there is also `\gitCommitterIsoDate`).

One only has to setup the `gitHeadInfo.gin` (that will contain the information read by the commands of the package) and the post-commit or post-checkout scripts in `.git/hooks`.

I guess that combining commands from `changes` and from `gitinfo2` can be easily done. However, just using `\usepackage[mark]{gitinfo2}` achieves the desired visual information on the output.